# Is every sheaf $\infty$-topos equivalent to sheaves on itself with respect to the canonical topology?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-topos-theory

Let $(\mathcal C, J)$ be a small [subcanonical](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subcanonical+coverage) [$\infty$-site](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-site), and let $Sh_J(\mathcal C)$ be the $\infty$-topos of sheaves thereon. Then $Sh_J(\mathcal C)$ is itself an $\infty$-site with respect to the [canonical topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+topology). There is a fully faithful Yoneda embedding $y: Sh_J(C) \to Sh_{can}(Sh_J(C))$.

**Question 1:** Is this functor an equivalence?

This question is motivated by Charles Rezk's question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345680/whats-an-example-of-an-infty-topos-not-equivalent-to-sheaves-on-a-grothendie/384160#384160). This question was asked [by David Carchedi](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95172/canonical-topology-for-infinity-topoi-revisited?noredirect=1&lq=1) assuming only that $Sh_J(\mathcal C)$ is an $\infty$-topos, not necessarily a sheaf $\infty$-topos. In that generality, I think the answer is *no*, but I've lost track of where I got that understanding from too.

At various times I've [thought](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52499804#52499804) I've known the answer to this question, but I find myself a bit confused tracing through some old conversations. Currently it seems to me this functor is fully faithful. Moreover, it seems to me (modulo size issues, which I think could be dealt with in the worst case by just a bit of universe-juggling) that every $F \in Sh_{can}(Sh_J(C))$ is covered by representables $F_i \in Sh_J(\mathcal C)$, and that each $F_i$ is covered by representables $C_{ij} \in \mathcal C$ by subcanonicity (and since any cover in $J$ is a cover in $can$ after applying Yoneda). Since covers are closed under composition, it seems to me that the $C_{ij} \to X$ form a cover of $X$ by objects of $\mathcal C$. This seems a short step from saying that $Sh_{can}(Sh_J(\mathcal C))$ is generated under colimits by $\mathcal C$, which seems quite close to saying that the answer should be "yes".

**Question 2:** Can some argument along the above lines be pushed to completion, or are there fundamental difficulties with this approach?

Comment: The answer is no, there is a counterexample in point 5 in https://mathoverflow.net/a/384160/20233, combined with point 3. The problem with the approach is that you can only build a hypercover this way.

Comment: To be more explicit the counterexample is given by the ∞-topos of presheaves on the poset {x_n, y_n | n ≥ 0} where each x_n and each y_n map to all x_k and y_k with k < n.